# Let $H$ be the semidirect product of $A$ and $B$ with respect to $\phi$. List all the elements in the centre $Z(H)$ of $H$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, cyclic-groups

Let $A=\langle a \rangle $ and $B = \langle b \rangle$ be cyclic groups of orders 2 and 8 respectively. Let $\phi: A \rightarrow Aut(B)$ be the homomorphism specified by $\phi(a) : b^i \rightarrow b^{5i}$ for all $0\leq i \leq 7$. Let $H$ be the semi-direct product of $A$ and $B$ with respect to this $\phi$. List all the elements in the centre $Z(H)$ of $H$.

So to begin with I have established the homomorphism. In plain notation, let $\{1,a\}$ and $\{1,b,b^2,b^3,b^4,b^5,b^6,b^7\}$.

$ \phi  =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & b & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & b^5 & b^6 & b^7 \\
1 & b^5 & b^2 & b^7 & b^4 & b & b^6 & b^3 \\
 \end{array} \right)$

Now, $H=\{ (1,1), (1,b), (1,b^2), (1,b^3), (1,b^4), (1,b^5), (1,b^6), (1,b^7), (a,1), (a,b), (a,b^2), (a,b^3), (a,b^4), (a,b^5), (a,b^6), (a,b^7) \}$.

Now, to list the elements in the centre. This is what I am somewhat confused by. Please let me know if this is right and whether I have missed anything from the centre.

In the case of $\phi(1)$,

$(1,k)(1,k')=(1*1,k^{\phi(1)}k')=(1,k k')=(1,k'k)=(1*1,k'^{\phi(1)}k)=(1*1, k'k)=(1,k')(1,k)$,

where $k,k' \in B$.

$(1,k)(a,k')=(1*a,k^{\phi(a)}k')=(a,k k')=(a,k'k)=(a*1,k'^{\phi(1)}k)=(a*1, k'k)=(a,k')(1,k)$,

provided only that $k', k \in \{1, b^2, b^4, b^6 \}$, and lastly

$(a,k)(a,k')=(a*a,k^{\phi(a)}k')=(1,k k')=(1,k'k)=(a*a,k'^{\phi(a)}k)=(a*a, k'k)=(a,k')(a,k)$,

provided only that $k', k \in \{1, b^2, b^4, b^6 \}$.

Therefore, we have that $Z(H)=\{ (1,1), (1,b^2), (1,b^4), (1,b^6), (a,1),  (a,b^2), (a,b^4), (a,b^6) \}$

Comment: Where you wrote "normalizer" I guess you actually meant "center"...didn't you? And observe that the quotient group $\;H/Z(H)\;$ **cannot** be cyclic non-trivial, so you commited a mistake as you get a center of order $\;8\;$ in a group of order $\;16\;$ : impossible. The center must have order either $\;2\;$ or $\;4\;$ ...

Comment: It is clear that $(a,1)$ cannot be in the centre, because your definition of $\phi$ tells us that  $a$ conjugates $b$ to $b^5$. (In fact the centre of this group consists of the first four elements in your list.)

Comment: Sorry, but how does (a,1) conjugate b to b^5? If we put a1 into the defined semi-direct product, we get $(a,1)(a,1)=(a*a,k^\phi(1)k')=$. Is it wrong to define $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(1)$ differently?

Comment: @DonAntonio do you  think that I misunderstood the question in making $\phi(a) $ and $\phi(1)$ different?

Comment: @CatherineDrysdale Perhaps. I honestly didn't read your whole post (I must go now...!). Try to use as simple a notation as possible.

Comment: I meant that $(a,1)$ conjugates $(1,b)$ to $(1,b^5)$. This is because $(a^{-1},1)(1,b)(a,1) = (a^{-1},1)(a,b^{\phi(a)}) = (1,b^5)$.

Comment: ah... How is it that the question would be answered ignoring my working...

Comment: All of your working is correct apart from the final sentence beginning "Therefore". You have proved that $Z(H)$ consists of the elements $(1.b^k)$ for $k=0,2,4,6$.

Comment: and there are no elements (a,b^k) that are in the centre? If so how?